# Getting the player with the most kills with a specific weapon [mysql]

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

Im trying to find the best killer (most kills) out of a kills database.
Put the killerId of $important into an array, and compare it with the rest of the killers. Find the best killer with the weapon $important.
How do I do that?

```
            $array = array();
            $index = 0;
            while($mData = $q->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $index++;
                $arr = explode('with ', $mData['killText']);
                $unimportant = array(" (in paintball)", " (in event)");
                $important = str_replace($unimportant, "", $arr[1]);

                if(empty($important)) { $important = "Suicide"; }

                $array[$important]['Kills']++;
                $array[$important]['Gun'] = $important;

                $query2 = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `kills` WHERE `killText` LIKE '%$important%' AND `killerID` = '". $mData['killerID'] ."'") or die($mysql->error);
                while($kData = $query2->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    // put the killerId of $important into an array, and compare it with the rest of the killers. Find the best killer with the weapon $important
                }
            }
```

Comment: Tip: Putting a MySQL query inside a `while` loop of another query's results is almost always a sign that you need to learn about `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `GROUP BY` will do the trick:

```
"SELECT killerID, COUNT(*) FROM kills WHERE killText LIKE '%$important%' GROUP BY killerID;"
```

You ca just fetch "killerID" and got the killer with most kills of weapon `$important`:

```
$kData = $query2->fetch_assoc();
$kData['killerID'];
```